# Create a spinner using a double array

Tags: android, arrays, android-spinner

I am trying to create a spinner which gets its values from a double array but i get the error: `java.lang.Double[], required int`, i have values such as `1.4` or `2.8` which is why i cant use an `int array`. My code is here below:

```
Double[] FULL = new Double[]{2.25,2.5,2.8};
adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,FULL,android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item);
```

I have tried converting my double array into an int array but that doesn't seem to work as well, i am relatively new to android so i may be doing the conversion wrong. Can i get some help?

Comment: Int indiacate the resources in Android . Default array adapter only takes String array . So just use quotes for double values .and use ArrayAdapter defined String Array

Comment: @ADM I need to get the values after that as a number to add to something, will this still work?

Comment: You just accepted the answer below. Which is same what i had suggested previously. And to  get Value you need to parse it with `Double.parseDouble(value)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the [ArrayAdapter.createFromResource()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#createFromResource(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int)) wrong. Please, refer to the documentation.

To fix your problem, add your `FULL` array to an array in `values > string.xml`

```
<array name="spinner_val">
    <item>"2.0"</item>
    <item>"3.0"</item>
    <item>"4.0"</item>
    ...
 </array>
```

Then retrieve them as strings since you are going to display them in a text.

```
ArrayAdapter.createFromResource (this, 
                getContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spinner_val), 
                R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item);
```

Comment: I need to get the values after that as a number to add to something, will this still work?